# Running a task multiple times in ssis(without a loop)

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012, business-intelligence

Here's the scene: I have tasks say A,B,C,D and E. I want task E to run after every other task completes, i.e. task E runs 4 times(after task A completes, then after task B completes, then after task C completes and after task D).

I tried to implement using OR constraint in the precedence constraint.

The problem is that the task E runs only once. Once it runs after task A, it's marked as done and it doesn't execute after other tasks(B,C & D).

Here's a screenshot of my implementation.[image]

Any ideas on implementing such logic? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don’t think is possible without including 4 copies of task E. Depending on what task E does, you may also need to consider running it  in series with A,B,C and D (as opposed to parallel) to avoid contention issues.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure you don't need to upkeep 4 version of the same task, put the task in it's own package and then use individual Execute Package Tasks that all point to the new package.

Comment: that is anyway similar to the approach of using separate tasks for each! doesn't provide any advantage.

Comment: Yeah, the only real advantage is you just have a single version of the task, so maintenance is easier.